# Problem facing while passing state to function based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass my state from a class based component to function based component. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280280/how-to-send-props-in-class-component-to-functional-component), but it cannot solve my error. How can I access the properties? What mistake am I making?

class component:

```
 const { userInfo } = this.state;
 <UserMenu {...userInfo}/>
```

Console error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/app/fuse-layouts/shared-components/UserMenu.js
  Line 18:32:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Properties I want to access:

```
address: ""
designation: (2) ["X", "Y"]
email: ""
id: "ABC"
name: "WER"
phone_number: "3456"
qualification: ""
role: "admin"
secondary_phone_number: ""
```

**Update:**

The function component is :

```
function UserMenu({id}) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [userMenu, setUserMenu] = useState(null);

    const userMenuClick = event => {
        setUserMenu(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const userMenuClose = () => {
        setUserMenu(null);
    };

    return (
        <>
           <Popover>
             ....

            </Popover>
        </>
    );
}

export default UserMenu;
```

I am getting this error : `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

**SOLVE:**
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573277/react-expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression)

Comment: `const user = ({userInfo}) => {userInfo}` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Somehow I didn't note that you updated your answer. I updated the code accrodingly. And the error was producing due to a missing parenthesis. Also, whenever i was getting `expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression`, doing this somehow resolved the error. That's why I did it despite of knowing what I was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the spread operator correctly

Change

```
<UserMenu {...{userInfo}}/>
```

to

```
<UserMenu { ...userInfo }/>
```

In child component, you can access all the properties of `userInfo` object directly on the props object

```
function UserMenu({ address, email, id }) {
    ....
}
```

Alternative approach to pass props from parent to child component is

```
<UserMenu userInfo={ userInfo } />
```

If you use second approach, then props object will have a property named `userInfo` on it containing all the user data you passed from parent component

```
function UserMenu({ userInfo }) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: If I change it this way, my VScode says it expects like they way I put the spread in my question. Console error says `Parsing error, Unexpected Token expected "..." <UserMenu {{...userInfo}}/>`

Comment: Now it is throwing `React: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` even though my syntax is alright

Comment: In case of the alternative (2nd) approach, How can I access the values? I am trying `userInfo.name` but it is showing me nothing.

Comment: try to log `userInfo` on the console and see what you get. Also make sure that you are using the same name as passed from the parent component

Comment: userInfo gives me all the properties, but whenever I try to access a single property like userInfo.name, it is giving me null

Comment: I can do the first way and can access all the values, but I need to pass the userInfo to a child component used in `UserMenu`

Comment: how are you accessing the `name` property? there must be a problem somewhere else in your code because props are being passed correctly from parent component and you have verified that by logging `userInfo` object on the console

Comment: I am accessing name by logging `userInfo.name`, which results `Typeerror: Cannot read property of null`. If I simple remove the `.name`, it shows all the properties

Comment: can you create a simple codesandbox demo of your problem and share the link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215600/discussion-between-proteeti-prova-and-yousaf).